# Spring cloud gateway integration test failure with Wiremock

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud-gateway, wiremock

I have an appliction which pretty much only routes to a wiremock endpoint if the incoming request matches the filter criteria.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
@Slf4j
public class aServiceController {

    @Value("${to.host}")
    private String toHost;

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder){
        return builder.routes()
                .route("path_route", r -> r.path("/pathvalue")
                    .uri(toHost + "/newpath"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

As you can see any requests with /pathvalue will be redirected to the toHost which i am specifying to be a wiremock host. So effectively becoming

```
http://<wiremockhost>/newpath/pathvalue
```

I have a stub setup in wiremock that will return a 200 here.

However while attempting to run i see these in the logs

```
2022-03-12 07:45:13.360 DEBUG 8184 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] org.apache.coyote.AsyncStateMachine      : Changing async state from [DISPATCHED] to [STARTING]
2022-03-12 07:45:13.361 DEBUG 8184 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl  : Firing onStartAsync() event for any AsyncListeners
2022-03-12 07:45:13.385 DEBUG 8184 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [3cc73b05] HTTP GET "/pathvalue"
2022-03-12 07:45:13.436 DEBUG 8184 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.s.w.r.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : [3cc73b05] Mapped to ResourceWebHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/]]
2022-03-12 07:45:13.453 DEBUG 8184 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.s.w.r.resource.ResourceWebHandler      : [3cc73b05] Resource not found
2022-03-12 07:45:13.540 DEBUG 8184 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [3cc73b05] Resolved [ResponseStatusException: 404 NOT_FOUND] for HTTP GET /pathvalue
```

So my test case which expects 200 keeps failing. Any inputs are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your configuration, the request will be forwarded to `http://<wiremockhost>/pathvalue` and not to `http://<wiremockhost>/newpath/pathvalue`.

In order to change path you need to apply filter

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder){
    return builder.routes()
            .route("path_route", r -> r.path("/pathvalue")
                    .filters(f -> f.rewritePath("/(?<segment>.*)", "/newpath/${segment}"))
                    .uri(toHost)
            )
            .build();
}
```

### Troubleshooting Spring Cloud Gateway

In some cases, spring gateway configuration could be tricky and it's always helpful to enable additional logging to see internal behavior

**application.yml**

```
logging:
  level:
    reactor:
      netty: TRACE
    org:
      springframework:
        cloud:
          gateway: TRACE
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        wiretap: true
      httpserver:
        wiretap: true
```